# Why is the output of wall command not displaying in stdout?

Tags: command-line

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I'm executing the `wall` command like this:

```
$ wall
Hi this is for testing
^d
```

But it doesn't display the message in terminal. I'm just executing the `wall` command in my machine; I'm not sending it to anyone. How could I solve this problem?

[image: Snapshot for wall command]

Thank You...

Comment: Test it in TTY . I had the same issue in 16.04 , where it doesn't display in GUI but does display in TTY. I suspect it may be a form of bug

Comment: But why its not working in GUI, My colleagues using the same version of Ubuntu 14.04.  But in those machines it's working in GUI...

Comment: Can you run it with strace so we see if it has any permissions issues perhaps? `strace -e open wall` should list numerous open(2) calls, and the last one should be something like `open("/dev/pts/0", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE) = ...`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't show that path. Instead of that it gives like this, `open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++`

Answer (score 1):

Type the `mesg` command, and if it says "`is n`" (messages from `wall` are blocked), do `mesg y`. Of course, do `man mesg;man wall` first.

Comment: I tested it, It gives 'y'. But the output is not displaying